# How do I register my azure subscription for Virtual Machine Scale Sets?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to try out Azure Container Service with mesos, but during deployment I got this message:

```
MissingRegistrationForType\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The subscription is not registered for the resource type 'virtualMachineScaleSets'
```

I can't find how I register my subscription for this anywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RPs have to be registered with a subscription before you can use them - if you use the Portal or PowerShell, those do it for you automatically...  If you need to manually register, as long as you're not using a subscription that has some limitation (trial, etc) you should be able to do it yourself.

If you have the Azure PowerShell cmdlets installed you can use:

```
Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Compute
```

Or going to the portal and creating a VMSS should also work.

Comment: do you know if that is available in cli on osx?

Comment: I created a VMSS and after that it seems like I was able to create a dcos.

Comment: For the CLI check out "azure provider register"

Answer (score 0):

Which region are you trying to deploy into?
I saw that error when trying to deploy the resource in the region where that resource or the sub-resource is not available. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services

Comment: Should be there. Trying to replicate now.

Comment: it should be available there according to the link you posted.